# how to do sqlite upsert using API and not hard coded string?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I want to upsert (update on insert if not exist) some rows in my sqlite table.

I saw this sqlite command:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Employee (id, name, role) 
  VALUES (1, 'John Foo', 'CEO');
```

How can I use this via code API?

I have thought to use:

```
if (db.update(SAVED_OFFERS_TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_UID,
        new String[] { values.getAsString(KEY_UID) }) == 0) {
    db.insert(SAVED_OFFERS_TABLE_NAME, // table
            null, // nullColumnHack
            values); 
}
```

Is there any more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `insert(...)`, use [`insertWithOnConflict(..., SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29). Or `execSQL()` to execute the raw `INSERT OR REPLACE` SQL.

Comment: is it better than my current way?

Comment: Yes, less round-trips to the database and avoids potential concurrency issues (something modifies the databae between update and insert).